# apex form is not fetching the correct data

Tags: forms, oracle, load, oracle-apex

Since I am new to Apex and don't really get to know how it works, I need to ask this question

I have 2 pages, first one is items to display data. each item from different table . Then a button to redirect to page 2, and this one works fine.

The second page fetch data from table according to select item in first page. Linked by 'redirect to page in application' on The button. 
The problem is that it displays the data of the last query not the current.

I want to know why it's not updating to last value and what to do to solve it.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link for your button is created when page 1 is rendered. This link will not change when the user picks from your select list.

Each time you navigate back from page 2 to page 1, the link is being rebuilt using the cached value of the select list. That's why the results you see on page 2 are always based on your previous selection.

To get the desired behaviour, you need to set the session state of the select list before passing it. There are various ways to achieve this. A good starting point would be to set your button to submit the page rather than redirect. Use a branch to pass the selected value across to page 2.